# Migrating email server

Tags: email, migration, mx-record

I'm migrating a small company's email from one simple setup to another.
The MX records remain with the original server.
Also, a CNAME points to the original server - I'm not sure why as I didn't set this up in the first place.
I have been able to use both server IP addresses on email clients to send emails.
I have been able to use the server IP addresses on email clients to receive email at the original server and NOT on the new server.  Not too surprising.
I'm wondering if there's a recommended way to test *receiving* on the new server before I change the MX records?
Or, is it recommended to just change the MX records (and the CNAME entry I suppose?) and then let the results propagate?

Comment: The MX records needs to specify an A record. Where does the CNAME record come into play?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options based on what kind of software you are able to configure.

If the server that you are sending the test messages **from** happens to be Exim, you could setup a manualroute that will skip DNS entirely, and send messages directly to your test server. Documentation and example here:
https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_manualroute_router.html#SECID123

It is very possible that other email servers have a comparable feature to this, but Exim is what I know, so I can't comment on other mail servers.

Your other option is to set up a DNS resolver (BIND for example) with your fake MX records in place. Then configure your sending email server to use your custom DNS resolver to resolve the DNS records. On Linux, you'd be able to edit the `/etc/resolve.conf` to change the resolver used by your mail server in a lot of cases.

Comment: Well, I'm not much of an expert in how these things work.  I already am addressing the servers using their IP addresses.  So, I've rather assumed that it's the destination email address domain that is steering the traffic to the original server.

Comment: Ah yes, in that case you likely just need to edit the routing on the new email server so that it doesn't route the messages to the original server. For example on a cPanel server this would be done by moving the recipient domain from the /etc/remotedomains file to the /etc/localdomains file.